# Unable to delete specific geometry using geo-nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to generate a structure made of wood-like planks using geo-nodes in blender 4.1.
To do that I am using a mesh with n extrusions as a base to define the overall structure and to place the planks I have attempted to split the mesh and scale each face along the Y-axis. I do some raycasting to find the distance to the nearest edge to know how wide the planks should be.

This approach works fine if I don't want to change the direction of the planks based on the structure "curves", but I want to be able to have areas where the planks are placed perpendicularly. So I have tried to remove edges based on a couple of rules, and after that I wanted to use the remaining points to find which faces of the split mesh have not been used yet and repeat the process of scaling those faces down to define the splines where the remaining planks should be placed.

The problem is that I am not able to delete the faces that I want. I have tried to use raycasts but with no success.
I am able to determine the points where the face is located(I capture the faces position using mesh islands + sample index), but after that I do not understand how to go around the comparison to delete geometry. Comparing positions fails, as well as comparing face indices after retrieving them using sample nearest.

Does anyone know how I could approach this issue or if there is an easier approach to achieve the result I want? If so, I would appreaciate your help.
Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help.

Here is my .blend file in case it is of help.
[image]

The current result is shown in the picture below.
I want to fill those blank faces with planks placed perpendicularly to the others, if that makes sense.

[image]

Comment: Hi Paolo, (while I dont have your answer, I just wanted to say) thanks for taking the tour and preparing your question so well! Welcome to blender.se <3